# Keras stuck at first epoch only when using validation generator

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am reading a book on deep learning named [Deep learning with python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294438). The book is old in terms of code but I read the official documentation to get through it. Anyways

This is a program that is supposed to train a simple model for time series prediction of temperature using dataset available [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/keras-datasets/jena_climate_2009_2016.csv.zip).

The program goes like this

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

#Loading file 
f = open(fname) # fname is the filepath for the csv file
data = f.read()
f.close()
lines = data.split('\n')
header = lines[0].split(',')
lines = lines[1:]

# Converting into numpy array
float_data = np.zeros((len(lines), len(header) - 1))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]
float_data[i, :] = values

# Normalizing the data 
mean = float_data[:200000].mean(axis=0)
float_data -= mean
std = float_data[:200000].std(axis=0)
float_data /= std
```

There is a generator function for creating the dataset (I've read `tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence` is a preferred choice but I failed in converting this generator to  Sequence subclass

```py
def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index, shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):
  if max_index is None:
    max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
  i = min_index + lookback

  while 1:
    if shuffle:
      rows = np.random.randint(min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
    else:
      if i + batch_size >= max_index:
        i = min_index + lookback

      rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
      i += len(rows)

    samples = np.zeros((len(rows),lookback // step,data.shape[-1]))
    targets = np.zeros((len(rows),))

    for j, row in enumerate(rows):
      indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
      samples[j] = data[indices]
      targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]
    yield samples, targets
```

Here are the parameter details

1) `data`—The original array of floating-point data, normalized

2) `lookback`—How many timesteps back the input data should go.

3) `delay`—How many timesteps in the future the target should be.

4) `min_index` and `max_index`—Indices in the data array that delimit which timesteps to draw from. This is useful for keeping a segment of the data for validation and another for testing.

5) `shuffle`—Whether to shuffle the samples or draw them in chronological order.

6) `batch_size`—The number of samples per batch.

7) `step`—The period, in timesteps, at which you sample data. You’ll set it to 6 in
order to draw one data point every hour.

And these generators

```py
lookback = 1440
step = 6
delay = 144
batch_size = 128

train_gen = generator(float_data,
lookback=lookback,
delay=delay,
min_index=0,
max_index=200000,
shuffle=True,
step=step,
batch_size=batch_size)

val_gen = generator(float_data,
lookback=lookback,
delay=delay,
min_index=200001,
max_index=300000,
step=step,
batch_size=batch_size)

test_gen = generator(float_data,
lookback=lookback,
delay=delay,
min_index=300001,
max_index=None,
step=step,
batch_size=batch_size)

val_steps = (300000 - 200001 - lookback)
test_steps = (len(float_data) - 300001 - lookback)
```

The network layout is as follows

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(lookback // step, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(), loss='mae')
history = model.fit(train_gen,steps_per_epoch=500,epochs=20,validation_data=test_gen,validation_steps=test_steps)
```

However the model gets stuck at

```
Train for 500 steps, validate for 119110 steps
Epoch 1/20
497/500 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3524
```

My model gets stuck while evaluating on the validation set. To make sure `train_gen` and `val_gen` where okay I tried

```
next(train_gen)
next(val_gen)
```

And they both display different values each time like

```
(array([[[ 0.34593055,  0.49507501,  0.4628141 , ...,  0.16203687,
           0.18470667,  0.84378526],
         [ 0.36243914,  0.6283707 ,  0.59460993, ...,  0.2921889 ,
           0.94414397,  0.60710086],
         [ 0.35182647,  0.64305582,  0.60912981, ...,  1.78242962,
           1.59631612,  0.43507171],
         ...,
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that your test_steps are correct? You are not using  the batch size to compute it, so its probably much larger than needed.

Comment: try with reducing batch size

Comment: @DulangaHeshan I have tried that, didn't work

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm not sure, it is an example I'm following from the book

Comment: The problem is that these steps computations are not using the batch size, so they are all wrong, since the number of steps change with the batch size. In the end if you put a value for validation_steps that is much larger than needed, will make the validation phase take much longer time which might seem to be stuck. I recommend that you divide these steps with the batch size

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you however I didn't fully understood you. *I recommend that you divide these steps with batch size* Can you post 'how do I divide the steps' as the answer?

Comment: Just test_steps = test_steps // batch_size

Comment: That worked, Thank you @Dr.Snoopy I wonder why the author didn't include that step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of validation steps looks suspicious, as it is not being calculated with the batch size, so it is larger than it should be which would extend the validation phase in time considerably. The solution is to divide the number of steps with the batch size:

```
val_steps = val_steps // batch_size
test_steps = test_steps // batch_size
```

This will make steps have the right value.